# No clock I2C STM32L0

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, i2c, stm32ldiscovery

Hi i am currently working on a project where i am using a murata cmwx1zzabz (The module is powered by an STM32L072CZ and an SX1276 transceiver).
The goal eventually is to send data from my sensor(VL53L1X) using lorawan to the internet.

So i started using the lorawan stack from ST on my st B-L072Z_LRWAN1 discoveryboard. When i tried to connect the sensor to the proccesor it didn't work.

I then decided to use a "Fresh" STM32cubeMX project where i wanted to make the I2C connection work.

By both of the projects there was nothing but a 330mV dc voltage on the CLK and SDA pins.

I am new to the whole STcube projects so i may be forgetting something obvious.
I have been  working on this problem for almost 18 hours now and am at this point i am trying to just get the SCL and SDA lines to work.

my code:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  uint8_t buf = 25;                                             // random value just to see if i can get the SCL and SDA lines to change  from value 
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1,0x18<<1,&buf,2,100000);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

---

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x00707CBB;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

---

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_I2C_Init(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
  /* Check the I2C handle allocation */
  if (hi2c == NULL)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_I2C_ALL_INSTANCE(hi2c->Instance));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_OWN_ADDRESS1(hi2c->Init.OwnAddress1));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_ADDRESSING_MODE(hi2c->Init.AddressingMode));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_DUAL_ADDRESS(hi2c->Init.DualAddressMode));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_OWN_ADDRESS2(hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_OWN_ADDRESS2_MASK(hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2Masks));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_GENERAL_CALL(hi2c->Init.GeneralCallMode));
  assert_param(IS_I2C_NO_STRETCH(hi2c->Init.NoStretchMode));

  if (hi2c->State == HAL_I2C_STATE_RESET)
  {
    /* Allocate lock resource and initialize it */
    hi2c->Lock = HAL_UNLOCKED;

#if (USE_HAL_I2C_REGISTER_CALLBACKS == 1)
    /* Init the I2C Callback settings */
    hi2c->MasterTxCpltCallback = HAL_I2C_MasterTxCpltCallback; /* Legacy weak MasterTxCpltCallback */
    hi2c->MasterRxCpltCallback = HAL_I2C_MasterRxCpltCallback; /* Legacy weak MasterRxCpltCallback */
    hi2c->SlaveTxCpltCallback  = HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback;  /* Legacy weak SlaveTxCpltCallback  */
    hi2c->SlaveRxCpltCallback  = HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback;  /* Legacy weak SlaveRxCpltCallback  */
    hi2c->ListenCpltCallback   = HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback;   /* Legacy weak ListenCpltCallback   */
    hi2c->MemTxCpltCallback    = HAL_I2C_MemTxCpltCallback;    /* Legacy weak MemTxCpltCallback    */
    hi2c->MemRxCpltCallback    = HAL_I2C_MemRxCpltCallback;    /* Legacy weak MemRxCpltCallback    */
    hi2c->ErrorCallback        = HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback;        /* Legacy weak ErrorCallback        */
    hi2c->AbortCpltCallback    = HAL_I2C_AbortCpltCallback;    /* Legacy weak AbortCpltCallback    */
    hi2c->AddrCallback         = HAL_I2C_AddrCallback;         /* Legacy weak AddrCallback         */

    if (hi2c->MspInitCallback == NULL)
    {
      hi2c->MspInitCallback = HAL_I2C_MspInit; /* Legacy weak MspInit  */
    }

    /* Init the low level hardware : GPIO, CLOCK, CORTEX...etc */
    hi2c->MspInitCallback(hi2c);
#else
    /* Init the low level hardware : GPIO, CLOCK, CORTEX...etc */
    HAL_I2C_MspInit(hi2c);
#endif /* USE_HAL_I2C_REGISTER_CALLBACKS */
  }

  hi2c->State = HAL_I2C_STATE_BUSY;

  /* Disable the selected I2C peripheral */
  __HAL_I2C_DISABLE(hi2c);

  /*---------------------------- I2Cx TIMINGR Configuration ------------------*/
  /* Configure I2Cx: Frequency range */
  hi2c->Instance->TIMINGR = hi2c->Init.Timing & TIMING_CLEAR_MASK;

  /*---------------------------- I2Cx OAR1 Configuration ---------------------*/
  /* Disable Own Address1 before set the Own Address1 configuration */
  hi2c->Instance->OAR1 &= ~I2C_OAR1_OA1EN;

  /* Configure I2Cx: Own Address1 and ack own address1 mode */
  if (hi2c->Init.AddressingMode == I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT)
  {
    hi2c->Instance->OAR1 = (I2C_OAR1_OA1EN | hi2c->Init.OwnAddress1);
  }
  else /* I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_10BIT */
  {
    hi2c->Instance->OAR1 = (I2C_OAR1_OA1EN | I2C_OAR1_OA1MODE | hi2c->Init.OwnAddress1);
  }

  /*---------------------------- I2Cx CR2 Configuration ----------------------*/
  /* Configure I2Cx: Addressing Master mode */
  if (hi2c->Init.AddressingMode == I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_10BIT)
  {
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 = (I2C_CR2_ADD10);
  }
  /* Enable the AUTOEND by default, and enable NACK (should be disable only during Slave process */
  hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= (I2C_CR2_AUTOEND | I2C_CR2_NACK);

  /*---------------------------- I2Cx OAR2 Configuration ---------------------*/
  /* Disable Own Address2 before set the Own Address2 configuration */
  hi2c->Instance->OAR2 &= ~I2C_DUALADDRESS_ENABLE;

  /* Configure I2Cx: Dual mode and Own Address2 */
  hi2c->Instance->OAR2 = (hi2c->Init.DualAddressMode | hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2 | (hi2c->Init.OwnAddress2Masks << 8));

  /*---------------------------- I2Cx CR1 Configuration ----------------------*/
  /* Configure I2Cx: Generalcall and NoStretch mode */
  hi2c->Instance->CR1 = (hi2c->Init.GeneralCallMode | hi2c->Init.NoStretchMode);

  /* Enable the selected I2C peripheral */
  __HAL_I2C_ENABLE(hi2c);

  hi2c->ErrorCode = HAL_I2C_ERROR_NONE;
  hi2c->State = HAL_I2C_STATE_READY;
  hi2c->PreviousState = I2C_STATE_NONE;
  hi2c->Mode = HAL_I2C_MODE_NONE;

  return HAL_OK;
}
_________
```

---

```
void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hi2c->Instance==I2C1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 0 */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration    
    PB9     ------> I2C1_SDA
    PB8     ------> I2C1_SCL 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
```

---

PS: i have tried a mbed example of the sensor on this discovery board and it works correctly.

Comment: The last time I looked, `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit` took a pointer as the third argument, It looks like you are passing a character. Don't you get at least a warning at the call?

Comment: @PaulR i did get a warining there. I have changed it like a thousand times over the last couple of days and forgot it the last time. didnt fix the problem but thanks. (right now the code is warning free)

Comment: Do you have pull up resistors? I2C does not work without it. The internal ones not always are strong enougs.

Comment: @P__J__   i do have pull up resistors. When i used mbed to check if all the components worked i saw the clock signal on the scope

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for the help.

i found out what the problem of my code was.

in the STM32L0xx_hal_msp.c file there is a function called `void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)` 
In this function the SCL and SDA pins are declared

```
__HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
/**I2C1 GPIO Configuration    
PB9     ------> I2C1_SDA
PB8     ------> I2C1_SCL 
*/
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_8;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;         // standard GPIO_MODE_AF_OD => GPIO_MODE_AF_PP (open drain mode to push pull mode )
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* Peripheral clock enable */
__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
```

Changing the mode of the pins fixed the problem.

Comment: Driving the I2C pins as PP in the master end is just wrong and not good for the other chips on the bus as they will try to drive them simultaneously during the STOP bits etc. If your board is missing strong enough pullups on the I2C you might end up seeing a relief by setting this to PP but you're just adding a bug to a bug so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the STM32L0.  But I looked at my STM32L4 examples.  One thing in my L4 I2C example that is missing from your code is configuring the I2C Clock source in `HAL_I2C_MspInit()`

```
/*##-1- Configure the I2C clock source. The clock is derived from the SYSCLK #*/
RCC_PeriphCLKInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2Cx;
RCC_PeriphCLKInitStruct.I2c3ClockSelection = RCC_I2CxCLKSOURCE_SYSCLK;
HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&RCC_PeriphCLKInitStruct);
```

If that is not applicable or doesn't help then I suggest you download the [STM32CubeL0](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubel0.html) package which should include an I2C example, maybe even for you specific board.

Comment: Okay after wanting to show how to fix the problem to a colleage switching back to open drain didnt create the problem again. I dont know how this is all possible but the problem is fixed